# putting all checked items in checkboxes in an array

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to take all the checked items in an html page and put them in an array to perform a certain action on it. I don't understand the fields of a checkbox(name, value,...). I am using html with ruby on rails!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it on the client side using javascript you can use jQuery like this:

```
var arr = $('[type=checkbox]:checked');
```

If you need to do this on the server side in ruby on rails I cannot help you. However I do know that only checked checkboxes will get send back to the server on a GET or POST, so if you  know what names these checkboxes you can get them from the request object and put them in a array. Non checked checkboxes will never get to the server, so you won't have to explicitly ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='User[]' VALUE='someVal'>Visible Text</option>
```

Whatever checkbox is checked by the user then submitted will be in a POST array called User.

Adding the [ ] to the name creates an array when submitted.

Not sure hot to do this in ruby on rails but in php. When the form is submitted but the user an array is passed to the server. We names our checkboxes as User so our posted array is called User. In php i retrieve the posted array like this:

```
print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS["User"]);
```

then this outputs the array like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Me [1] => You [2] => SomeoneElse )
```

all of the data in the array were check checkboxes. the you can do a

```
foreach (​​​​​​​ $HTTP_POST_VARS["User"] as $key => $value) { $key is 0, $value is Me. and so on }
```

Hope this helps –

Comment: so If I want to loop on this array in a certain action(to check on a certain attribute user) , how can I get it??

Comment: Not sure hot to do this in ruby on rails but in php. When the form is submitted but the user an array is passed to the server. We names our checkboxes as User so our posted array is called User. In php i retrieve the posted array like this: print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS["User"]); then this outputs the array like so: Array ( [0] => Me [1] => You [2] => SomeoneElse ) all of the data in the array were check checkboxes. the you can do a foreach (​​​​​​​ $HTTP_POST_VARS["User"] as $key => $value) { your code } Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is already an array of everything within the `form` set.  Use this to do your *"certain action"* on the checkboxes.  If for whatever reason you need the information in a different variable, then just loop through the `$_POST` and put it into a different variable like so:

```
while ($row = $_POST) {
   $new_var[] = $row[0];
}
```

That should work for you to put into a new/different array but frankly, I don't see the point of that since it's already an array.

As far as understanding the way the array of $_POST looks like, then `var_dump()` it and see.  The name of the checkbox will be that in `[]` and the value will display after the `=>`.  So if your input is named `name=box1` and the value is `value=1` then the array, from the `$_POST` standpoint, would look like `[box1] => 1` so you can then use this section by calling it specifically like `$foo = $_POST['box1']` and the value of `$foo` would be the value of `box1` or you can do whatever else you want with that (rather than put into a new variable) by calling it.